# Solr - Solr Deployment not showing in Jboss

Tags: solr, jboss7.x

I have `Jboss 7` running in Linux system. and I had deployed `Solr 3.5` in it. It was working fine before.

After some days, Today when I started jboss 7 , it does not start my `solr 3.5` . my `sorl.war` file exist at `jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/`

such issue also occured some times before, when my `war` deployment shows `solr.war.failed` in deployments. and i was able to resolve it by just moving / renaming that file.

But currently I am unable to deploy my was file and not showing as running when I start Jboss.

Below is response when i start jboss

> =========================================================================
>
> JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final
>
> JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java
>
> JAVA_OPTS: -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
>
> =========================================================================

I also tried by creating war file again and again deploy it.

Please help me to resolve this issue. how can i make it running??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your solr.war is placed in jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/ and add an empty file named solr.war.dodeploy right next to the war.. If the deploy fails, copy the full stacktrace of the error.